# Django import CSV with carriage return

Tags: python, django, postgresql, csv

I'm creating a Django app and I need to import several `*.csv` files.
One's of this file has this structure:

```
id|value (header)

12|¤this is the

value¤

34|¤this is another

value¤
```

I use this code for parse the file:

```
try:
    csvfile = open(path, "r", encoding='utf-16')
except IOError:
    return False
cursor.copy_from(csvfile , tblname, columns=['id', 'value'], sep='|')
```

But when I try to parse this file, it gave me this error:

```
psycopg2.DataError: ERROR:  missing data for the column "value"
```

Is there a way to parse this file keeping carriage return inside text identifier (`'¤'`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Pythons `csv` module for reading that.

```
import csv

try:
    csvfile = open(path, newline='')
except IOError:
    return False

csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar='¤')
for row in csvreader:
    print(', '.join(row))  # or do something else with the row of data.
```

Comment: You have couple of options here as I see it. Either using `copy_expert` to write line by line or use methodology used here http://bonesmoses.org/2014/07/25/friends-dont-let-friends-use-loops/

Comment: Not very elegant, but i create this:
try:
    csvfile = open(path, newline='')
except IOError:
    return False

csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|', quotechar='¤')
for row in csvreader:
    cursor.execute(INSERT INTO " + table_name + " (id, value) VALUES ('" + row[0] + "', '" + row[1] + "')")

at least it works

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to build up the entries yourself as follows:

```
blocks = []
block = []

with open('input.csv') as f_input:
    for row in f_input:
        if '|' in row:
            if len(block):
                blocks.append(''.join(block).strip('\n').split('|'))
                block = []
            block.append(row)
        else:
            block.append(row)

if len(block):
    blocks.append(''.join(block).strip('\n').split('|'))

print(blocks)
```

This would produce a list of blocks as follows:

```
[['id', 'value (header)'], ['12', 'Â¤this is the\nvalueÂ¤'], ['34', 'Â¤this is another\nvalueÂ¤']]
```